# Babel 7 doesn't change CONST to VAR

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I have problem with Safari version <= 9.
Babel doesn't seem to replace const with var.

I get this error in console:

**Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode.**

I tried using @babel/preset-stage-0 but babel removed it.

This is my app configuration:

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign"
  ]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const componentName = "contact-captain";
const publicFolderRelativePath = "../../../../public/js";
const ignorePlugin = new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/);


module.exports = {
    // devtool: "source-map",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, publicFolderRelativePath),
        filename: `${componentName}.js`
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        ignorePlugin
    ]
};
```

Comment: Cao Olga. What do you mean by "@babel/preset-stage-0 but babel removed it"?

Comment: When I try to build my project I get this error: we've removed Babel's Stage presets.
Please consider reading our blog post on this decision at
https://babeljs.io/blog/2018/07/27/removing-babels-stage-presets
I'm not sure what to use instead

Comment: Ok. Didn't know. Thanx!

Comment: I have the same problem. Whatever config in .babelrc I set, it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

did you try to configure `preset-env` ?
you can find the browsers list here: https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist

probably need to add `Safari 8` in your list...

```js
["@babel/preset-env", {
  "targets": {
    "browsers": ["last 2 versions"],
  }
}]
```

Comment: Look at that list, find how to add safari, and the version you need. This is a very well tested plugin, I am sure it works as expected

Comment: I tried like this: 
  "browsers": [
            "last 1 version",
            "> 0.25%",
            "Safari >= 7",
            "iOS >= 7"
          ]

And also, by adding .browserslistrc file. But doesn't seem to help

Comment: Then you should definitely have a deeper look into browserlist and how it works

Comment: I'm having the same issue (`const` not being converted to `var` breaking iOS <= 9) and unfortunately no changes to the `.browserslistrc` help. When I run `npx browserslist` to see the browsers it quite clearly dumps `ios_saf 8`. In fact, changing my `.browserslistrc` to just "last 999 versions" (which causes `npx browserslist` to dump an outrageously large list) **still** doesn't fix it

Comment: After a further hour of research I believe I've traced my issue to something tangentially related (webpack loaders failing to run for modules imported via a package.json's `main` directive). Redacting my downvote while I investigate. My issue could be unrelated.

Comment: Hi @stevendesu, the idea of downvoting an answer because it doesn't solve your particular issue might not really be on the spirit of so. The upvote was there because it really helped someone once... If you didn't find what you need, try to keep searching and eventually open a request to the babel project itself :).
I wish you fix your issue asap! Cheers!