# Babel not transforming const (no loaders running on subdirectory)

Tags: javascript, webpack, browser, babeljs

### Update

After over an hour of exploration and debugging I believe I've figured out the **cause** of my issue, but still need a solution.

My project has a directory structure like so:

```
/
|- dist/
|- src/
|- plugins/
|- node_modules/
|- webpack.config.js
|- .babelrc
|- ...
```

The `plugins` directory holds git submodules referencing VideoJS plugins that I've written. These plugins are each their own stand-alone project (with their own `package.json`). When importing and using these plugins I do the following in `src/index.js`:

```
import videojs from "video.js";
import "./plugins/AutoplayFixPlugin";

videojs("my-player", { plugins: { autoplayFixPlugin: {} } });
```

Per the [Node module resolution algorithm](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together), this will:

1. See that the path starts with `./` and try to load the module as a file
2. Recognize that `AutoplayFixPlugin` is a directory and try to load the module as a directory
3. Fail to find an `index.js`, `index.json`, or `index.node` file
4. Succeed in finding a `package.json` file
5. Parse the `package.json` file for its `main` field, and load that file

In this way the import `./plugins/AutoplayFixPlugin` properly loads `./plugins/AutoplayFixPlugin/src/plugin.js`

Here's the problem: When I import a module this way, ***none*** of my loaders run. It simply imports the raw source code and Babel is never executed on my plugin.

I've tried replacing `./plugins/AutoplayFixPlugin` with `./plugins/AutoplayFixPlugin/src/plugin.js` in my import statement, but this didn't help, either. I think the presence of a `package.json` in the subdirectory is tripping up Webpack (or Babel) somehow.

### Update 2

I've confirmed that removing the `package.json` causes Babel to run as expected on the plugin files. Adding it back, Babel stops working. I've tried adding a `.babelrc` file to the plugin directory, but this also doesn't work. I tried installing `@babel/core` and `@babel/preset-env` locally to the plugin, but this also doesn't work.

For some reason Webpack loaders are not running (or at least Babel is not running) in any subdirectory that has a `package.json` file.

### Original Post

I have the following setup for my project:

`webpack.config.js`:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const TerserWebpackPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = (env, argv) => ({
    devtool: argv.mode === "development" ? "inline-source-map" : "source-map",
    devServer: {
        contentBase: "./dist",
        host: "0.0.0.0"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "babel-loader",
                        options: {
                            cacheDirectory: true,
                            cacheCompression: false
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg|svg)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "url-loader",
                        options: {
                            limit: 5000
                        }
                    },
                    "img-loader"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new TerserWebpackPlugin({
                sourceMap: true,
                cache: true,
                parallel: true,
                terserOptions: {
                    compress: {
                        drop_console: true
                    }
                }
            })
        ]
    },
    performance: {
        maxAssetSize: 9e9,
        maxEntrypointSize: 9e9
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./index.html"
        })
    ]
});
```

`.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "debug": true,
                "include": [
                    "transform-block-scoping"
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

`.browserslistrc`:

```
# Browsers that we support
last 2 versions, not dead, > 1% in US
# Microsoft no longer provides security updates for IE <= 10
ie >= 11
# Apple no longer provides updates for the iPad Mini
ios >= 9
```

Running `npx browserslist` I get the following output:

```
and_chr 71
and_ff 64
and_qq 1.2
and_uc 11.8
android 67
android 4.4.3-4.4.4
baidu 7.12
chrome 72
chrome 71
edge 18
edge 17
firefox 65
firefox 64
ie 11
ie_mob 11
ios_saf 12.0-12.1
ios_saf 11.3-11.4
ios_saf 11.0-11.2
ios_saf 10.3
ios_saf 10.0-10.2
ios_saf 9.3
ios_saf 9.0-9.2
ios_saf 8
op_mini all
op_mob 46
opera 58
opera 57
safari 12
safari 11.1
samsung 8.2
samsung 7.2-7.4
```

In particular I'm interested in the `ios_saf 9.0-9.2` line (and arguably `ios_saf 8` as well). I have an iPad Mini on my desk running iOS 9.3.5 and Safari is throwing an error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode.
```

It's clear from the error that the `const` keyword is not getting transformed to `var`. Doing some investigation is looks like [there may be two steps to this transformation](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2473): `const -> let` via `es6.constants`, then `let -> var` via `es6.blockScoping`

Looking at `node_modules/@babel/preset-env/data/plugin-features.js` I see a line for `transform-block-scoping`, but I see no such line for `transform-constants` or similar. Looking at [Babel's official list of plugins](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/plugins), there is also no `constants` plugin. Just `block-scoping` (which converts `let` to `var`)

I wondered if maybe `transform-constants` was rolled into `transform-block-scoping` ([an idea that seems to be confirmed by their docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-block-scoping#constant-checks)), so I looked to see if `transform-block-scoping` was being run at all by enabling the `debug` option in Babel:

```
@babel/preset-env: `DEBUG` option

Using targets:
{
  "android": "4.4.3",
  "chrome": "71",
  "edge": "17",
  "firefox": "64",
  "ie": "11",
  "ios": "8",
  "opera": "57",
  "safari": "11.1"
}

Using modules transform: auto

Using plugins:
  transform-template-literals { "android":"4.4.3", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }
  transform-literals { "android":"4.4.3", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }
  transform-function-name { "android":"4.4.3", "edge":"17", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }
  transform-arrow-functions { "android":"4.4.3", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }
  transform-block-scoped-functions { "android":"4.4.3", "ios":"8" }
  transform-classes { "android":"4.4.3", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }
  transform-object-super { "android":"4.4.3", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }
  transform-shorthand-properties { "android":"4.4.3", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }
  transform-duplicate-keys { "android":"4.4.3", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }
  transform-computed-properties { "android":"4.4.3", "ie":"11" }
  transform-for-of { "android":"4.4.3", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }
  transform-sticky-regex { "android":"4.4.3", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }
  transform-dotall-regex { "android":"4.4.3", "edge":"17", "firefox":"64", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }
  transform-unicode-regex { "android":"4.4.3", "ie":"11", "ios":"8", "safari":"11.1" }
  transform-spread { "android":"4.4.3", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }
  transform-parameters { "android":"4.4.3", "edge":"17", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }
  transform-destructuring { "android":"4.4.3", "edge":"17", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }
  ---> transform-block-scoping { "android":"4.4.3", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }
  transform-typeof-symbol { "android":"4.4.3", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }
  transform-new-target { "android":"4.4.3", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }
  transform-regenerator { "android":"4.4.3", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }
  transform-exponentiation-operator { "android":"4.4.3", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }
  transform-async-to-generator { "android":"4.4.3", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }
  proposal-async-generator-functions { "android":"4.4.3", "edge":"17", "ie":"11", "ios":"8", "safari":"11.1" }
  proposal-object-rest-spread { "android":"4.4.3", "edge":"17", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }
  proposal-unicode-property-regex { "android":"4.4.3", "edge":"17", "firefox":"64", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }
  proposal-json-strings { "android":"4.4.3", "edge":"17", "ie":"11", "ios":"8", "safari":"11.1" }
  proposal-optional-catch-binding { "android":"4.4.3", "edge":"17", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }
  transform-named-capturing-groups-regex { "android":"4.4.3", "edge":"17", "firefox":"64", "ie":"11", "ios":"8" }

Using polyfills: No polyfills were added, since the `useBuiltIns` option was not set.
```

At least according to the debug output, it looks like `block-scoping` is running. I also, just for the heck of it, updated my `.browserslistrc` to the following:

```
last 999 versions
```

Even after this it ***still*** wasn't transforming `const` to `var`.

I also double-checked that the issue wasn't coming from the (excluded) `node_modules` folder in two different ways. First, looking at the source code, I saw that the bug was occurring in the following general region of `main.js` (circa line 72500):

```
/***/ "./plugins/AutoplayFixPlugin/src/AutoplayFixPlugin.js":
/*!************************************************************!*\
  !*** ./plugins/AutoplayFixPlugin/src/AutoplayFixPlugin.js ***!
  \************************************************************/
/*! exports provided: default */
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony import */ var video_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! video.js */ "./node_modules/video.js/dist/video.es.js");
/* harmony import */ var _utilities_Logger__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ../../../utilities/Logger */ "./utilities/Logger.js");
/* harmony import */ var _utilities_Logger__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_utilities_Logger__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__);
/* harmony import */ var _package_json__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ../package.json */ "./plugins/AutoplayFixPlugin/package.json");
var _package_json__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___namespace = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.t(/*! ../package.json */ "./plugins/AutoplayFixPlugin/package.json", 1);
/* harmony import */ var _AutoplayFixPlugin_scss__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./AutoplayFixPlugin.scss */ "./plugins/AutoplayFixPlugin/src/AutoplayFixPlugin.scss");
/* harmony import */ var _AutoplayFixPlugin_scss__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_AutoplayFixPlugin_scss__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__);
/* harmony import */ var _components_AutoplayMuteOverlay__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./components/AutoplayMuteOverlay */ "./plugins/AutoplayFixPlugin/src/components/AutoplayMuteOverlay.js");

const Plugin = video_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["default"].getPlugin("plugin"); // Default options for the plugin.

const defaults = {
  muted: false,
  inline: false
};
```

This is my own code. Still, just to be ***100% sure***, I removed the `exclude` line from my `webpack.config.js`. This increased my compile time from ~2 seconds to ~30 seconds, for whatever reason changed the line number of my error from ~72500 to ~43600, and otherwise had no effect. My code still fails on the iPad Mini due to:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode.
```

I'm running low on ideas for how to debug this. Why is Babel not converting `const` to `var`, given that the browsers I'm targeting ***clearly*** don't support it? Even with the target expanded to `last 999 versions` it still isn't performing this transformation.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52362780/babel-7-doesnt-change-const-to-var

Comment: @IsaacVidrine I did find that (6 month old) post and it didn't have an answer to my problem. Ultimately Hitmands said "Find out how to add Safari [to your browserlistrc], I'm sure it works as expected", olga_babic responded with her browserslistrc (which looked fine), and Hitmands replied "Then you should definitely have a deeper look into browserlist and how it works". Nothing helpful.

Comment: Have seen this? https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3928

Comment: @IsaacVidrine Unfortunately that issue is concerning a `const` being added by `webpack-dev-server`. My issue lies with a `const` in my own code (not an NPM dependency). Still, I tried updating the `exclude` line in my `webpack.config.js` for the `babel-loader` loader to `/node_modules(?!\/webpack-dev-server)/`. Unfortunately this did not fix my issue.

Comment: So the code that isnt being transpiled comes from a module you wrote that lives in node_modules folder? If thats the case try removing node_modules from webpack exclude. Might make building a lot more hefty but in theory would work if you have node_modules that need transpiled. Also if that works, I would probably re write your module using es5 syntax

Comment: It comes from a module I wrote that lives in the `plugins` folder. I'm including the plugin as a git submodule, **not** as an NPM dependency.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. I was looking at the docs, and not sure if this is solution but you may need to call out the `babel-plugin-transform-block-scoping` plugin in `.babelrc`. Heres the docs on it https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-transform-block-scoping.html. I see you already include it with `preset-env` but dont actually specify it as a plugin.

Comment: Have you read through to Babel docs for config files and how to use the `babelrcRoots` option in a `babel.config.js`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth So looking into the `babelrcRoots` let me to [The monorepo documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#monorepos), which caused me to find a very simple solution to my problem. Apparently if you have multiple packages in subdirectories you **must** use a `babel.config.js` file, not a `.babelrc` file. I renamed `.babelrc` to `babel.config.js` and appended a `module.exports = ` to the front of it, and like magic everything started working!